# Looks or lack of style, nerd

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would be so grateful if you paraphrase the following paragraph with simple words. Note that this paragraph refers to a way of self-deprecating yourself in your speech.

> "Looks or lack of style: We all try, but we can't call be cool. In
>   order for some of us to be cool, some of us have to look like nerds.
>   If that's you, use it. Maybe you're talking about science, or maybe
>   about fancy basketball stats - whatever it is, rock your nerdiness."

Answer (score 1):

“We all try to have good looks but we can’t be cool. The only way for some of us to be cool is for some of us to look like nerds. If that’s you, be nerdy. Whether you are talking about science or fancy basketball statistics, own and be proud of your nerdiness.”

I don’t really think this is about self-deprecating yourself in speech; I think it’s about being “cool” by seeming like a nerd instead of having good looks.

Comment: But it is about self-deprecating yourself in the speech. You can search the sentences on the net. Google books will show it. Your explanation is good, thanks. But I don't know the meaning of nerd here that matches to "lack of style", a way of being "cool" and showable during talking about basketball stats or science.

Comment: @user358597 Nothing about the passage implies criticism or self-deprecation. *Being cool* is being used as a positive, not a negative, and a lack of style is a simple statement of fact, not any kind of judgment.

Comment: I have the book, the title of the section is about self-deprecation. If it were possible I could show it. In fact the author does not use it as a negative factor. She suggested it as away of attraction the audience and have fun with them.